# MySQL intertwine two queries based on previous query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with: id, client, domain and bytes. I have a query that gets the top 3 users either by client:

```
SELECT client FROM log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

or by domain

```
SELECT domain FROM log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Is there a way in MySQL to get this two mixed without a stored procedure? For example, get the top 3 clients, each client row followed by the top 3 domains used BY THAT CLIENT in a single query execution?

- 192.168.1.1

  - google.com
  - facebook.com
  - twitter.com
- 192.168.1.2

  - facebook.com
  - twitter.com
  - ...
- ...

For example, to get the top 3 domain usage from client 192.168.1.1:

```
SELECT domain FROM log
WHERE client = '192.168.1.1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

So for each row in query #1, somehow this query should be executed. So far I got to show a concatenated list of top domains for each client, sadly not related to the same client because I can't access `outer_client` in subquery:

```
SELECT client AS outer_client, top_domain
FROM log
JOIN (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.domain) AS top_domain 
   FROM (
      SELECT domain 
      FROM log
      WHERE client = outer_client 
      GROUP BY 1 
      ORDER BY SUM(bytes)
      LIMIT 5
   ) t
) k
GROUP BY client
ORDER BY SUM(bytes)
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Yeah, every row in log is a hit from a client to a domain which gets some amount of bytes, hence the column bytes works for usage either by clients or domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc1b1/2/0

```
SELECT client
  , (SELECT domain
      FROM log
      WHERE client=top_clients.client
      GROUP BY client, domain
      ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
      LIMIT 1) domain1
  , (SELECT domain
      FROM log
      WHERE client=top_clients.client
      GROUP BY client, domain
      ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) domain2
  , (SELECT domain
      FROM log
      WHERE client=top_clients.client
      GROUP BY client, domain
      ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) domain3
FROM (SELECT client FROM log GROUP BY client ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC LIMIT 3) top_clients;
```

My output:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| client      | domain1      | domain2      | domain3     |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 192.168.1.1 | google.com   | facebook.com | twitter.com |
| 192.168.1.2 | facebook.com | twitter.com  | NULL        |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Yeah that's it! Is there a way to get an arbitrary number of domains? For example 10 without repeating? Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: @einundswanzig Yes, there is a way. use temporary tables.

Comment: Working on a way to have arbitrary no. of domains, will have it shortly ... stay tuned.  It will be all in a statement -- no stored procs, no views, no temp tables.

Comment: Maybe another day. I know it's possible, but turning out to be rather difficult to get the general case. I was looking to use the GROUP_CONCAT to make a comma-separated list of domains, so it would scale.  But the lack of windowing functions like `RANK` makes it not so easy, and it's difficult to pass through variables through a double-nested subquery.  Anyhow thanks for the upvote and checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to PHPMySQL, and your server allows it, what you're looking for is a VIEW.

You write your SQL to get your data set.  And rather than saving it in a temporary table (which would make it static), you save it in a VIEW.  Once you have that view, you can always use it the same as if it were a table.  In fact, it actually SHOWS the data set in a table format as if that's exactly what it was.
You can run queries against it, with JOINS...  Anything you would do with a table.
And it's actual live data.

Comment: It would be cool if could get it done in a command, is it possible?

Comment: Why is this downvoted, as it 100% correct?!  Anyway...  What do you mean "a command"?

Comment: A single query execution, not views, not stored procedures, not php or other language intervention.

Comment: According to what I read, he specified "no stored procedure".  I don't see anything about views.

Comment: Compensatory upvote. I probably would have recommended a VIEW if it were one of my users.

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  See, my thinking is that this is a better answer than the question itself.  That is, he started off thinking of it the incorrect way.  And I understand why "stored procedure" was left off.  Many DBAs don't allow access to those things (I work as a data analyst, and I can't get to Sprocs on servers here).  Views are far less dangerous, and usually available.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
select client,
substring_index(group_concat(domain order by sumbytes desc), ',', 5) as top5domains
from (
  select client, domain, sum(bytes) as sumbytes
  from log
  group by client, domain
) cd
group by client
order by sum(sumbytes) desc
limit 5;
```

Courtesy of @Gordon Linoff here: [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT from subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336887/mysql-group-concat-from-subquery/24336948#24336948)

Answer (score -1):

According to your question, you are ordering by the same thing in each example. If that's the case, the row you return should have both client and domain already in it. So would this solve your problem?

```
SELECT client, domain FROM log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Nop that will get me one domain per client(and not even the most used by that client), I need top client #1 followed by the 3 top domain used BY THAT CLIENT.