# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a concat list from every row in an outer query but I get `Unknown column 'outter_client' in 'where clause'` elsewhere I saw that you can't access an outer variable from a subquery, is there a way to reformulate this query without stored procedures, views or temporary tables and get it working?

```
SELECT client AS outer_client, top_domain
FROM log
JOIN (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.domain) AS top_domain 
   FROM (
      SELECT domain 
      FROM log
      WHERE client = outer_client 
      GROUP BY 1 
      ORDER BY SUM(bytes)
      LIMIT 5
   ) t
) k
GROUP BY client
ORDER BY SUM(bytes)
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: you cannot reference a column alias of an outer query in the JOIN condition of an inner query. Use table aliases ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the top five domains for each client, based on the number of bytes.  You can do this using nested selects and the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select client,
       substring_index(group_concat(domain order by sumbytes desc), ',', 5) as top5domains
from (select client, domain, sum(bytes) as sumbytes
      from log
      group by client, domain
     ) cd
group by client
order by sum(sumbytes) desc
limit 5;
```